# resize div width down based on the amount of data contained within repeater and up to a max-width

Tags: asp.net, html, repeater, css

I have a repeater wrapped in a div which displays results as horizontal text. The div is set to a maximum width of 450px which causes the results to wrap onto the next line which is perfect, but the width remains 450px when there are less than 450px width's worth of results. I would like the div to resize down to the width of the results.

This is the data wrapping ok in the div:

[image: Results wrapping ok]

This is what happens when there are a small number of results:

[image: Results not resizing down]

This is what I would like to happen:

[image: Results resized down]

Here is my css for the div:

```
        div.SelectedStudents {
            background-color: lightyellow;
            font-family: verdana, tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            border:solid 1px black;
            max-width:450px;
            text-align: left;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            padding: 5px;
            line-height:1.5em;
        {
```

Here is my div and repeater:

```
           <div class="SelectedStudents"> 
               <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsProgressCohorts" onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="Column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column1") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Column1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column1") %>' Font-Bold="True" />
                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>               
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEmptyData" Text="No Data To Display" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
           </div>
```

**EDIT:**

After applying `display:table;` to css I lose the spaces between each result:

[image: display:table;]

Got around this by adding a space `+ ' '` to my select statement inside the SQL stored procedure I am calling to retrieve the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to add is `display: table`.  It acts similar to inline-block in that it shrinks to fit the content, but without having the element appear inline.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/12tg3bge

```
div.SelectedStudents {
    background-color: lightyellow;
    font-family: verdana, tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    max-width:450px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height:1.5em;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: This works great thank you very much, however there is a problem. I've lost the spaces between each result generated by the repeater. See new screenshot in question.

Comment: I've tried display:table-cell; which now looks correct however I have the div nested in a div which centers elements on the page and setting the nested div to display:table-cell aligns the div right.

Comment: Edited my stored procedure and added a space to the select statement in order to get around this. Your solution worked. Many thanks, I never would have worked this one out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width to auto in the css:

```
div.SelectedStudents {
        background-color: lightyellow;
        font-family: verdana, tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        border:solid 1px black;
        max-width:450px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: 5px;
        line-height:1.5em;
        width: auto;
    }
```

if it does not work set the width of all the other containers inside the div to auto as well.