# Centering H1/Class horizontally, dynamic width with shrink-to-fit border

Tags: html, css

I've a problem accomplishing what I want with CSS:

Stylesheet:

```
/* firstHeading */
.firstHeading {
background-color:#9f9f2c;
padding:10px;
font-family: 'BankGothic Md BT', Machine;
font-variant: small-caps;
text-transform: capitalize;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: x-large;
color:#ffff95;
border-style: ridge;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: gray;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">List title</h1>
```

The challenge: This looks effectively exactly how I want it, but now I need to center this horizontally (not vertically) across the page, while keeping the border and background fill color to be similar in size to how they are - purely in CSS. The "List title" can be very short or very long - dynamic width.

As you can see, I tried setting margins on left and right to auto. Most suggestions at this point I see suggest setting a width, like 'width:100%;'. When I've done so, it centered across the page, but it really stretched the background "block" and I'd like that to be more form-fitting. The other suggestions I read also made it not dynamic width, and I then had issues with wrapping.

I also can't wrap in another div in the HTML: it's already wrapped in a div called "content" - the HTML is generated code from a MediaWiki page. If we center "content", we center more than just the heading but the rest of the page content, and I want that to be left-aligned.

Suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [resize div width down based on the amount of data contained within repeater and up to a max-width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064137/resize-div-width-down-based-on-the-amount-of-data-contained-within-repeater-and)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to center an `inline-block`, which can really only be done by setting `text-align: center;` on the parent element.

You can first, set the `h1` to `display: block;` and `text-align: center;`.  After that, you can use a `span` inside of the `h1` for your background/border effect.  Doing this will allow the span to sit centered within the h1 tag, without the width of the span expanding outwards.

**HTML:**

```
<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">
    <span>List title</span>
</h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* firstHeading */
.firstHeading {
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    *zoom: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.firstHeading span {
    background-color:#9f9f2c;
    padding:10px;
    font-family: 'BankGothic Md BT', Machine;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: x-large;
    color:#ffff95;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: gray;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/s2kjY/

Comment: That looks exactly how I want it... but I cannot easily edit the HTML to insert a span because the HTML is generated by a wiki. I'm basically creating a wiki skin with CSS.

Comment: Basically, I don't want the other skins to have to change, or edit the wiki source.

Comment: Unfortunately, I really see no way to achieve this without modifying the markup.  If it's critical to have, I suggest looking into modifying the wiki template.

Comment: Okay, I figured out a hack:
Further CSS styling of Wiki page:
body {
text-align:center;
}

#bodyContent {
text-align:left !important;
}

#footer {
text-align:left !important;
}

made my firstHeading centered like you have it, Axel, but the rest left-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Elements must have an explicit width set in order to center them horizontally with auto margins. If you're using `display: inline-block` then you should be able to center it with `text-align: center`.